# when myItems is an empty array, it is saying 'myItem.map() is not a function'. how to solve?

Tags: reactjs, typeerror, react-component

When items are present in myItems state, the website is ok. but if there is no item, the website breaks.

```
const [myItems, setMyItems] = useState([]);

return (
<div className="container my-5">
  <div className="row g-5">
    {
      myItems?.map(myItem => <MySingleItem key={myItem._id} myItem={myItem} handleItemDelete={handleItemDelete} />)
    }
  </div>
</div>
);
```

Comment: Can you show the whole component... How you are adding items to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is your `myItems` is actually receiving a value that is not an array type.

Doing

```
const myItems = 'b';
myItems.map((a) => a)
```

will give the same error `Uncaught TypeError: myItems.map is not a function`.

It's telling you `.map` is not a function because the data type of the value of `myItems` at that point in time is something else.

Check your usage of `setMyItems` in the rest of your component code or share the full code because I believe you're setting it as a non-array type by mistake.

Comment: Yes, got it. Thank you so much. I had to check the type and put conditions according to it. It solved the problem.